# Classic ASP code inside HTML Form TextArea input return as text from Access database

Tags: forms, ms-access, variables

I want to insert with form TextArea input HTML with ASP code to Access 2000 database.

This is OK, but when retrieve the `recordset` from an ASP page, the part of ASP code is just text. What I'm doing wrong?

What I have tried:

The Insert Code:

```vb
<%
    Set MM_editCmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
    MM_editCmd.ActiveConnection = MM_conn_STRING
    MM_editCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO KioskLayout (KioskHtml) VALUES (?)" 
    MM_editCmd.Prepared = true

    MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param5", 203, 1, 536870910, Request.Form("KioskLayHtml")) ' adLongVarWChar
    MM_editCmd.Execute
    MM_editCmd.ActiveConnection.Close
%>
```

The HTML Form Code:

```html
<form METHOD="POST" name="Layout" action="<%=MM_editAction%>" class="center">
  <textarea class="form-control" id="KioskLayHtml" name="KioskLayHtml">
<!--This is The TextArea field Input --> 
  <div class="grid-container">
<div class="main"><%=rs("today")%></div>
<div class="Left"><%=rs("tomorrow")%></div>
<div class="Bottom"><%=rs("yesterday")%></div>
</div>
<!--End Of TextArea field Input --> 
  </textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="Layout">
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

But when retrieve the `recordset` from an ASP page shows this as text.

```vb
<%=rs("today")%>
<%=rs("tomorrow")%>
<%=rs("yesterday")%>
```

and view the page source shows this:

```html
<div class="grid-container">
<div class="main"><%=rs("today")%></div>
<div class="Left"><%=rs("tomorrow")%></div>
<div class="Bottom"><%=rs("yesterday")%></div>
</div>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

IS the file saved as .ASP ? It appears to be pure HTML in which case what's between brackets won't be parsed on the server.

Comment: Yes, the file where retrieves the recordset is an .asp file. It is HTML code loaded from a database recordset, and ASP code embedded within that database value.